# Custom Plymouth Splashes?

Tags: 12.10, plymouth

I am working on trying to make my own plymouth boot screen, but the internet doesn't seem to have that many articles about it. I was hoping someone could give me a crash course on what to do to make one. What exactly is needed and has to be edited? Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Check this link for general plymouth info. In particular take a look at the "External Resources" section at the end of the page for links to tutorials etc.

[Freedesktop Plymouth page](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth)

Also, take a look at this page for an intro to the Plymouth scripting language:

[Freedesktop Plymouth scripting page](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth/Scripts)

Comment: Noted. On a long shot, I was hoping to create a theme that is simple like the iOS boot screen (replace the apple logo with the ubuntu logo) and maybe add a spinning progress wheel. Know of any themes that I could modify found online? :)

Comment: Well, I guess the default ubuntu-logo theme isn't a bad place to start!